# Change Wordpress Posts' last_modified date and time with WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change the last modified date and time of all of my blog's posts in WordPress. So far i have....

```
add_action( 'wp', 'asd' );
function asd()
{
    $post_list = get_posts( array(
    'post_per_page'    => '-1'
    ) );

    foreach ( $post_list as $post ) {
   // $posts[] += $post->ID;

    $postID = $post->ID;
    $datetime = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );  
    echo $postID . ' ||| ' . $datetime . '<br>';

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "UPDATE `$wpdb->posts` SET `post_modified` = '" . $datetime . "'  WHERE ID = " . $postID);
}
}
```

I get no errors or whatsoever. I am using "echo" for debugging purposes. I have two problems.

1. I have 6 posts and i get only 5
2. It seems that no update is happening in the database, for the last modified field

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use this code.( paste it in your theme function.php)

```
add_action('init','change_mypost_date');
function change_mypost_date(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' =>  'property_listing',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $datetime  = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );  
            $current_post = array(
                  'ID'           => get_the_ID(),
                  'post_modified' => $datetime
              );
            // Update the post into the database
              wp_update_post( $current_post );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked!!! I just changed 'init' to 'wp' and it did the job! Thank you!!!

Comment: :D Great have a nice journey.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to update all of your posts' date to current datetime. So, the solution is without requiring any loops:

```php
add_action( 'init', function () {

    $hook = 'run_snippet_daily';
    $args = array();

    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( $hook, $args ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', $hook, $args );
    }
} );

add_action( 'run_snippet_daily', function () {
    
    $datetime = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );  
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( "UPDATE `$wpdb->posts` 
                   SET `post_date`='{$datetime}', 
                  `post_modified` ='{$datetime}' 
                   WHERE `post_type`= 'post' ");
} );
```